# Mysql - How to count only unique visits

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I'm adding 1 view for the page every time it refreshes. I'm storing page_id, user's ip, and browser agent.

I want to select and count only unique visits.

So I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as visits FROM sh_page_visits GROUP BY ip_address
```

But it returns 4 instead of 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would imagine that id's are probably not unique per ip_address. So, for example, if you have 5 records - four of which come from the same ip_address they would all have different id's. Have you tried doing the count on the ip_address field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
select count(distinct ip_address) from sh_page_visits
```

This counts how many distinct ip addresses have visited the site - which is how I understood your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. this what I was looking for.